# jqgrid get multiple selected rows ordered as grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to get the ids from `'selarrrow'` sorted as shown in the grid.

```
mygrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')
```

The problem is the ids are appended to `'selarrrow'` as the user clicks on each row, so the result of `'selarrrow'` does not keep the order of the data in the grid.

How can I retrieve selected rows-data in the grid order? (or another method instead of `'selarrrow'`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `selarrrow` is array of rowids of selected rows. You can use

```
var rowIndex = mygrid.jqGrid("getInd", rowid);
```

to get the index of every row (the index of the first row of the grid is 1, the index of the second row is 2 and so on). Thus you can sort the ids based in the row index.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, How can I sort the ids after get row index? In the end, I want to have an array with all selected rows-data ordered like grid.

Comment: @Aberel: You are welcome! You can use the standard [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of JavaScript array for example. You need just provide your compare function as the callback parameter. It should compare the rowid. You can use something like `arr.sort(function(rowid1, rowid2) { return mygrid.jqGrid("getInd", rowid1) - mygrid.jqGrid("getInd", rowid2); })`